# Do HTML/CSS/JavaScript define constants representing system theme colours?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Do HTML/CSS/JavaScript define constants representing system theme colours? I mean those colours a user can define in the operating system (or a browser) control panel. Like standard window contents background and text colours etc.

The idea is to make a web site to respect the user preferences by default, showing light text on dark background in case the user uses such a theme in his system (while following the Occam's razor principle by avoiding introducing extra configuration).

Comment: Yes, css 2.0 system colors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can,

Open firebug and change some css declaration like color : ActiveBorder or see [webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/blsystemcolors.htm](http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/blsystemcolors.htm) or search the net for 'css system colors'

- ActiveBorder : Active window border.
- ActiveCaption :   Active window caption.
- AppWorkspace  Background color of multiple document interface.
- Background    Desktop background.
- ButtonFace    Face color for three-dimensional display elements.
- ButtonHighlight   Dark shadow for three-dimensional display elements (for edges facing away from the light source).
- ButtonShadow  Shadow color for three-dimensional display elements.
- ButtonText    Text on push buttons.
- CaptionText   Text in caption, size box, and scrollbar arrow box.
- GrayText  Grayed (disabled) text. This color is set to #000 if the current display driver does not support a solid gray color.
- Highlight     Item(s) selected in a control.
- HighlightText     Text of item(s) selected in a control.
- InactiveBorder    Inactive window border.
- InactiveCaption   Inactive window caption.
- InactiveCaptionText   Color of text in an inactive caption.
- InfoBackground    Background color for tooltip controls.
- InfoText  Text color for tooltip controls.
- Menu  Menu background.
- MenuText  Text in menus.
- Scrollbar     Scroll bar gray area.
- ThreeDDarkShadow  Dark shadow for three-dimensional display elements.
- ThreeDFace    Face color for three-dimensional display elements.
- ThreeDHighlight   Highlight color for three-dimensional display elements.
- ThreeDLightShadow     Light color for three-dimensional display elements (for edges facing the light source).
- ThreeDShadow  Dark shadow for three-dimensional display elements.
- Window    Window background.
- WindowFrame   Window frame.
- WindowText    Text in windows.

For a [better reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#system-colors) **suggested by unor** about system colors

Comment: Unfortunately, this is deprecated. I need a way somehow to detect, only if the user has a dark or a light theme and adjust my theme accordingly. It is a shame, that that ist not possible: I don't like to see very bright websites when I have a dark system theme.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS 2.1** specifies "[System Colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#system-colors)":

> In addition to being able to assign pre-defined color values to text, backgrounds, etc., CSS2 introduced a set of named color values that allows authors to specify colors in a manner that integrates them into the operating system's graphic environment.

Example:

> to set the foreground and background colors of a paragraph to the same foreground and background colors of the user's window, write the following:
>
> ```
> p { color: WindowText; background-color: Window }
> ```

In **CSS Color Module Level 3**, these system colors are [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css-system), "in favor of the CSS3 UI ‘`appearance`’ property". But it seems that this has been [dropped](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#changes-list), too (you can still find it in [older drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-ui-20030703/#appearance)).